# How to get all the rows except one in R

Tags: r

How do I get a whole matrix except a desired line?

I know this is probably a simple question but I'm not getting there.

```
line <- matrix[index,]
```

This gets me a desired line. I would like the opposite.

I've tried `line <- matrix[!index,]`, but I get an empty matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `index` is a numeric value you could use:

```
line <- matrix[-index,]
```

`!index` only works for logical values.

Comment: Thank you. :) It's just like that.